# How to number a list with multiple ngfors in a div in angular

Tags: angular

I have multiple `ngfor`s outputting an `undefined` number of results which I’d like to list in the following format with incremental numbering

EXPECTED OUPUT:
1. Object 1 News: Object 1 Stuff
2. Object 1 News: Object 1 Stuff
3. Object 1 News: Object 1 Stuff
4. Object 1 News: Object 1 Stuff
5. Object 2 News: Object 2 Stuff
6. Object 2 News: Object 2 Stuff
7. Object 2 News: Object 2 Stuff
8. Object 3 News: Object 3 Stuff
9. Object 3 News: Object 3 Stuff

CURRENT OUTPUT:
1. Object 1 News: Object 1 Stuff
Object 1 News: Object 1 Stuff
Object 1 News: Object 1 Stuff
Object 1 News: Object 1 Stuff
Object 2 News: Object 2 Stuff
Object 2 News: Object 2 Stuff
Object 2 News: Object 2 Stuff
Object 3 News: Object 3 Stuff
Object 3 News: Object 3 Stuff

I don’t know how I can make sure the numbered counter is preserved across these ngfors. Can I place a `let i = index` in the div? I can’t seem to get it to work.

The current output below only displays "1" for the first result, but the rest are not numbered:

```
<div *ngFor="let i=index;>
<tr *ngFor="let value of Object1”>
                <div *ngIf="convertDate(value.Max_Date) == convertDate(getTodaysDate())">
                        <h4 style="text-align:left;">{{ i }} ●<b> Object 1 News</b></h4><h5 style="text-align:left;">Object 1 Stuff</h5>
                </div>
</tr>
<tr *ngFor="let value of Object2”>
                <div *ngIf="convertDate(value.Max_Date) == convertDate(getTodaysDate())">
                        <h4 style="text-align:left;">{{ i }} ●<b> Object 2 News</b></h4><h5 style="text-align:left;">Object 2 Stuff</h5>
                <br>
                </div>
</tr>
<tr *ngFor="let value of Object3”>
                <div *ngIf="convertDate(value.Max_Date) == convertDate(getTodaysDate())">
                        <h4 style="text-align:left;">{{ i }} ●<b> Object 3 News</b></h4><h5 style="text-align:left;">Object 3 Stuff</h5>
                <br>
                </div>
</tr>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. What is currently happening with the present attempt? 2. Also, what are the contents of the objects you are iterating over? Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I only get "1." for the first result (edited above my attempt). the contents are string outputs.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't help. My question is what is the data you are currently working with and what is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrongly using `ngFor` on the first `div`. You need to get the `index` in each for-loop and secondly you need to add `Object1.length` in the second loop's index to get the correct number. Similarly, you need to add `Object1.length` & `Object2.length` in third loop's index to get the correct iteration number as per your requirement.

The following code will give you the required output:

```
<div>
    <tr *ngFor="let value of Object1; let i=index>
        <div *ngIf="convertDate(value.Max_Date) === convertDate(getTodaysDate())">
            <h4 style="text-align:left;">{{ i + 1 }} ●<b> Object 1 News</b></h4><h5 style="text-align:left;">Object 1 Stuff</h5>
        </div>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let value of Object2; let i=index”>
        <div *ngIf="convertDate(value.Max_Date) === convertDate(getTodaysDate())">
            <h4 style="text-align:left;">{{ i + 1 + Object1.length }} ●<b> Object 2 News</b></h4><h5 style="text-align:left;">Object 2 Stuff</h5>
            <br>
        </div>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let value of Object3; let i=index”>
        <div *ngIf="convertDate(value.Max_Date) === convertDate(getTodaysDate())">
            <h4 style="text-align:left;">{{ i + 1 + Object1.length + Object2.length }} ●<b> Object 3 News</b></h4><h5 style="text-align:left;">Object 3 Stuff</h5>
            <br>
        </div>
    </tr>
</div>
```